# Origin of "Everything lasts forever" argument?

Tags: time

Following is an argument that because moments exists outside of time, they can't fundamentally be said to "pass", except perhaps from our perspectives. I want to know where this argument originates.

> Time is composed of indivisible instants. Because time is derived from
>   these instants, the instants are not themselves subject to time.

I know about Dedekind and Cantor formalising continuums. Where was the bit that follows first made explicit?

Cheers.

Comment: See the post: [what-is-an-instant-of-time ?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/289924/what-is-an-instant-of-time)

Comment: If "moments" are *instants of time*, what does it mean to say that "they exist outside of time" ?

Comment: Building a house out of bricks doesn't mean the existence of the bricks is dependent on the house, but the other way round. That's the analogy. Not saying it's right, just wondering where it came from.